# No upgrade option when booting from USB (12.04)

Tags: upgrade, 12.04

I am trying to upgrade my ubuntu 11.10, i know that it is better to upgrade using a live cd/usb, i booted from the live usb, followed the instructions as usual, but only found three options:

1. Cleen install
2. Install alongside your other operating systems
3. Other

The upgrade choice was missing. I even tried installing it after running ubuntu 12.04 from usb, and ended up with the same result.

*I have a dual boot Ubuntu 11.10 and Windows 7, i think it is only seeing the windows 7 and missing the ubuntu 11.10 partition.*

Any help ?

Comment: This is usual if there is not enough space in your ubuntu partion ,How much space is left in your ubuntu partition?

Comment: +upgrading using cdrom/usb is not a good choice , Because it may erase most of your packages ,So try online upgrade if you have a stable internet connection

Comment: I don't think space is an issue, since i have 154 GB of free storage on my ubuntu partition.
Anyway i started the online upgrade, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a working internet connection after booting the live cd/usb?

I found the option was greyed-out for me too due to not having a working internet connection (the wifi was dropping in/out).

I connected via ethernet, rebooted the live USB and then the upgrade option was no longer greyed out. I suspect the upgrade option requires a network connection because not all packages are available in the live cd/usb image, as commented on in this answer:  [Can i update from "ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso" file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125947/can-i-update-from-ubuntu-12-04-desktop-i386-iso-file)