# Can i update from "ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso" file?

Tags: upgrade, 12.04

update speed is so slow, and i have download the new iso file:ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso, can i update directly from the iso file ?
my version is 11.10, Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

### Upgrading by using the CD or USB image

If you are using 10.04 LTS or 11.10 and you either insert the live CD or boot from the live CD to start installing it will give a option of upgrading to 12.04. It will automatically detect installed applications and install the updated version of your applications also.

If you download an ISO, the recommendation is to perform a [md5sum check](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31888/how-to-verify-that-the-iso-i-downloaded-is-bootable-before-i-burn-it) to ensure both the ISO downloaded and the burned CD are valid.

- **Upgrade from 10.04 LTS** (here shown with dual boot):

NOTE: Upgrades from 10.04 to 12.04 are not activated yet, see this question for more detail:

- [Why is "No new release found" when upgrading from a LTS to the next?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125392/no-new-release-found-when-upgrading-a-from-10-04-lts-to-12-04-lts)
- **Upgrade from 11.10**
  [image]

Taken from [12.04LTS upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-from-10-04-or-11-10-to-12-04)

Comment: Very grateful to your picture,I will try

Comment: im glad to help you.if you have any prob feel free to ask.

Comment: I've done a boot disk, restart the computer now ..

Answer (score 2):

I tried that and did work for me. I think the desktop `ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso` CD `iso` does not include the upgrade packages.

My advice for you is: you should download `ubuntu-12.04-alternate-i386.iso`(which is got all the upgrade packages) and then mount using the following command.

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/cdrom  
sudo mount -o loop ~/Desktop/ubuntu-12.04-alternate-i386.iso /media/cdrom
```

- A dialog will be displayed offering you the opportunity to upgrade using that CD. If the upgrade dialog is not displayed for any reason, you may also run the following command using `Alt+F2`:

`gksu "sh /media/cdrom/cdromupgrade"`

Comment: This is good method, but  if did'nt connected to internet   existing packages may lose :)

Comment: if i use ubuntu-12.04-alternate-i386.iso, results is the same as install from ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso? Thank you for answering.

Comment: @zhanggang please see my the edited one :)

Comment: @I'mnotthisperson I'm not sure on that. but he have internet connection but the update is very slow for him ;)

Comment: I've tried this and when my dialog appeared it said that it must download 1 Gb od data, so I assumed that it's not using data from my .iso image at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you burn it to a cd and boot it, and start the installation process you should be able to select the "upgrade" option in the menu.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can! Just boot via Live CD/USB, click Install on welcome Page, after that, click 'Continue' (You can optionally download updates while installing). In the installation type, select "Upgrade Ubuntu 11.10 to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS" and click Install Now... You are done.
This will keep your old files, etc while upgrading the OS.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have done the upgrade though a startup disk of ubuntu using ISO image. It works fine, [this will help you](http://ubuntusolved.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-11041004-to.html).