# How to upgrade ubuntu-13.04 using a downloaded iso without burning cd or liveusb within ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: upgrade

This is a popular question, I tried this suggestion [Can i update from "ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso" file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125947/can-i-update-from-ubuntu-12-04-desktop-i386-iso-file) ,  but problem is `gksu "sh /media/cdrom/cdromupgrade"` asks for a password, and even if I enter the correct password it says wrong. and BTW, I don't see any cdromupgrade file file in my `ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso` . So, what is the way to upgrade WITHOUT USING THE LIVE-USB OR CD within ubuntu from an ubuntu iso?

Comment: See if [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/340156/install-ubuntu-from-iso-image-directly-from-hard-disk-of-a-system-running-linux/340171#340171) helps.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply use the terminal commands to upgrade via internet.

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

For a development version, use

```
do-release-upgrade -d
```

Refer the following link.

http://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html