# Should I choose to Install alongside windows 8 or something else

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, system-installation

I'm thinking about installing Ubuntu ( dual boot ) as I might like it but I'm not sure whether I should choose to install alongside Windows 8 or something else.

I do have 100 GB unallocated already for Ubuntu on my `D:/` drive so I'm good to go.

I've seen people configure their partitions specially ( they created `swap` and then used the remaining unallocated to install Ubuntu ). Do I need to do this? Or will the installer handle it for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I go, **never** trust automatic partitioning options in Ubuntu installers, as you may end up with nasty surprises. When installing Ubuntu, personally I *always* prepare the partitions manually. Since you want to keep a dual-boot set-up, most flexible would be to create a new `extended` partition and inside it create the several `logical` partitions.

In the `extended` partition I usually I reserve:

- 5GB for `swap` (or whatever appropriate given your RAM)
- 25GB for `/` which will contain all your system files (but some will say that this is overly generous, as 15-20GB could suffice given your installation habits)
- the rest for `/home` which will contain all your user data

I tend to use `ext3` file system for the above partitions for reliability reasons (but you could of course use `ext4` or `reiserfs` if you so prefer). Sometimes I include a `/boot` partition no bigger than 500MB using `ext2`, but I cannot remember if this is more hassle than necessary; from memory, this is where kernels and `grub` config files end up.

Additionally, see [My approach for replacing current Ubuntu with newer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401521/my-approach-for-replacing-current-ubuntu-with-newer) for a discussion on how manual partitioning can be approached.

Comment: If i were to prepare partitions manualy, what partitions would I have to create besides swap and the standard Ubuntu install ( if any )

Comment: Thanks! to clarify, what does the /boot partition do and is it nessecary to install?

Comment: From memory, this is where kernels and `grub` config files end up. I vaguely remember that it *could* be a good idea to keep them separate from `/` partition.

Comment: So if I leave the /boot partition out, the config files will basically be re-routed to the / partition?

Comment: Yes, that's why separate `/boot` isn't really necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I think i'm going to leave the /boot partition out as i'm still new to Linux. Another question ( last one I promise ) / is the Ubuntu installation itself and /home is the user data partition correct?

Comment: Also what type of partition would i use when creating these. There are 2 options ( primary and logical ) And does it matter if I use ext3 or ex4?

Comment: Thanks! I understand it now :) buuut anotehr question ( this is really the last one ) After creating the 3 partitions I would highlight the extended partition and click install right?

Comment: I don't remember. You have to associate each partition to the appropriate mount point. But perhaps this is is already the topic of a separate question?

Comment: Yea I'll try looking around thanks for all the help :)

Comment: If Windows 8 came pre-installed, the computer is likely to have UFEI and GPT. thus the point about primary versus extended is moot. All the partitions can be primary.

Answer (score 0):

Do it alongside, this way if you don't like it you can turn back,

The installer will take a portion of the HDD as its own and format it to *EXT* (this is invisible to Windows 8) and a slight portion for linux-swap (which has its own format type) you can predetermine this on install.

To dual boot the installer should set it up for you with grub, but if not easyBCD, will do the same task from the Windows 8 side.