# How do I remove Ubuntu 18.04 and install Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: system-installation

I am new to Ubuntu, so how can I remove Ubuntu 18.04 and again install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS? Some software are not  working properly in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Install Ubuntu on the same partition. Possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: You can follow this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/49869/how-to-roll-back-ubuntu-to-a-previous-version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My approach for replacing current Ubuntu with newer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/401521/my-approach-for-replacing-current-ubuntu-with-newer)

Comment: I recently replaced 18.10 with 18.04. All I had to do is boot from 18.04 and during the installation option display, it offered to replace 18.10 with 18.04. I think if you try the same with a 16.04 DVD, it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to perform a **fresh installation** of Ubuntu 16.04. During the installation, existing installations of other operating systems can be wiped out.

How someone needs to proceed depends on the specific configuration and needs. The installer has a few default options. If these choices do not meet the needs of the user, the user can select *Something else*. Then, it is up to the user to inspect/change the partitioning of the drive and designate the mount points for the new installation.

Standard options of the installer include:

- Have Ubuntu use the entire disk.
- Install Ubuntu in addition to existing operation systems in free space on the disk. Optionally, the installer can create free space from an existing Windows installation.

Thus, if you only want Ubuntu 16.04 on your computer, you can select the option to have Ubuntu use the entire disk.

If you only want Ubuntu, but there is another partition on the disk that you want to preserve, you will need to select *Something else*. Then, you will be able to designate the system partition of your current Ubuntu 18.04 to become the system partition of your new Ubuntu 16.04 installation, and indicate that that partition must be reformatted (select the "ext4" file system). Depending on your use and needs of the other partition, you can have it automounted in your new installation as well. Only be careful that for the other partitions, the check mark "Format" is *not* set to prevent the installer from erasing this other partition.